# What does the に in 見るに全員が全員 do?

Tags: grammar

> 一団は種族がてんで統一されていない冒険者で、**見るに全員が全員**、生半可じゃない実力を漂わせているような....。

I'm not sure how to interpret this phrase. What does the に do in this phrase?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's equivalent to `見るところ` ([dictionary link](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D)). `全員が全員` is equivalent to `全員が` but gives extra emphasis, i.e. `everyone without a single exception`.